# Search a word by Capital or small letter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two values in the database like

1. `This is Name`
2. `this is a name`

I am searching a phrase `th` by SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE title LIKE '%th%'
```

then both filed is showing where I want only to show `this is a name` part. How should I proceed. I have tried preg_merge and other parts but they didn't work. Is there any SQL Query which can `distinguish capital and small letter`. Or any php method by which I can search exact term. My table format is UTF8. Not Latin General.

Comment: Change COLLATION of your column to case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will work for you, try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE BINARY title LIKE '%th%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I was wanting exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE title COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE '%th%'
```

**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)**

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:

More importantly

> If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case sensitive or binary collation. See Section 13.1.10, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”.

Comment: Sorry for the less info. My table format is UTF8. Not Latin General. So Collation will be utf8_general_ci. But its not working over there. And I can not change the collation format of the field as that filed is linked with many other fields.

Comment: That latin general doesn't have to be an exact remedy to your issue, It is there to just give you an idea how to solve the problem. You can easily change the collation names in the query, just like you'll have to change table name.

Comment: Yes I understood. But I tried the query by Collate utf_general_ci and it didn't work. I know utf8 will not support the case sensitive part so I got confused somehow. And I can't change the collation type of the field.

Comment: Then probably Prafulla's answer will help

Comment: Yes it helped. Thanks Hanky for the support.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to select words beginning with an lowercase.

This query check if the first character is an lowercase by the function LOWER() and if the following character is a lowercase with the same function LOWER().

If you want to assure that all the following characters are lowercase you can use LOWER(SUBSTRING(word FROM 2))

```
SELECT title
FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE (SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1) COLLATE latin1_bin) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)) 
AND (SUBSTRING(title, 2, 1) COLLATE latin1_bin ) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(title, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

$keywords = '%'.strtolower($_GET['q']). '%';

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE LOWER(item_code) LIKE '$keywords' ");

Comment: Adding explanation along with your code will help a lot :)